# How to understand the statement 'are only available on instances of the class' in the section about Private instance methods in ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_methods)(emphasis mine):

> ##### Private instance methods
>
> Unlike their public counterparts, private instance methods:
>
> - are only available on instances of the class, not on its .prototype property.

I tried to understand 'are only available on instances of the class, not on its .prototype property.' and wrote the following code:

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
}
const method = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
// are only available on instances of the class
method.#privateMethod
// not on its .prototype property
ClassWithPrivateMethod.prototype.#privateMethod
```

Private instance methods cannot be called from external code, so why does it say 'are only available on instances of the class'? What does 'available' refer to? Does 'its' in 'its .prototype' refer to ClassWithPrivateMethod or instances?

Comment: They can be called within the instance, but not from outside. So another method in the class could call `this.#privateMethod()` but  as you noted you won't see it anywhere in external code

Comment: The private method cannot be accessed outside the class. `method.privateMethod()` throws an error, and `ClassWithPrivateMethod.prototype` shows no methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's private, you can only refer to it from within a method of the class, so your example gets errors for both uses since you're trying to access the property outside the class.

To see the distinction that MDN is making, you have to try to use the method from within another method of the class, so I've added a public method.

From there you can see that you can access the method when it's called on an instance of the class. But if you try to call it on the class prototype, it gets an error.

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  #privateMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
  publicMethod() {
    console.log(this.#privateMethod()); // works
    console.log(ClassWithPrivateMethod.prototype.#privateMethod()); // fails
  }
}

let instance = new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
instance.publicMethod();
```

Comment: Also, using `ClassWithPrivateMethod.prototype.publicMethod()` as a static method will throw an error